# MobileServiceClient with Offline Sync PullAsync rows from last 10 days only

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to do a "what's new" type of list from the last 10 days from a sync table.

I don't want to sync the whole table down as it contains tens of thousands or rows--just rows that have `CreatedAt` from the last 10 days.

```
await App.syncTablePersonStringChange.PullAsync(
    "whtsnew",
    App.syncTablePersonStringChange.Where(x=>DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Subtract(x.CreatedAt) <= TimeSpan.FromDays(10)),
    false,
    new CancellationToken(),
    new PullOptions());
```

I've tried the code above, but it takes a long time (never finishes).

No errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your **where** statement. I have tried your statement and I get an **NotSupportException**:

> System.NotSupportedException: The member 'Subtract' is not supported in the 'Where' Mobile Services query expression.

This works for me:

```
.Where(x => x.CreatedAt >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-10));
```

But in this statement, the **offset** from `CreatedAt` will be ignored...